# How does zip and zip_longest work with iterables in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-itertools, iterable

This is my code snippet

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
args = [iter(list1)] * 4

zipped = zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None)
for j in zipped:
    print(j)
```

I was expecting it to output something like

```py
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'b')
('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
('d', 'd', 'd', 'd')
('e', 'e', 'e', 'e')
('f', 'f', 'f', 'f')
('g', 'g', 'g', 'g')
('h', 'h', 'h', 'h')
('i', 'i', 'i', 'i')
('j', 'j', 'j', 'j')
```

but it outputs

```py
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('e', 'f', 'g', 'h')
('i', 'j', None, None)
```

which is what I wanted anyway. I'm just confused, because as I understand it, `zip` and `zip_longest` pairs each item element wise. If `args` should have the same iterator object reference four times and have the same first, second, etc element, then why is this outputting the original list in succession?

Answer (score 1):

To see what is happening:

```
[list(x) for x in [iter(list1)] * 4]
#[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], [], [], []]
```

Rather you can do:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
args = [list(iter(list1))]*4

zipped = zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None)
for j in zipped:
    print(j)

#output
('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'b')
('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')
('d', 'd', 'd', 'd')
('e', 'e', 'e', 'e')
('f', 'f', 'f', 'f')
('g', 'g', 'g', 'g')
('h', 'h', 'h', 'h')
('i', 'i', 'i', 'i')
('j', 'j', 'j', 'j')
```

or

```
[iter(list1) for _ in range(4)]
```

as suggested by@InSync

Comment: Why did the first one make three empty lists? I don't quite understand since multiplying the iterable object four times makes four copies of that object and references it in the same memory